# Has One vs Belongs To in GORM

Tags: database, go, go-gorm

What is the difference between `Has One` and `Belongs To` in GORM?
Where is each used?

I read the documentation, but I did not understand the difference and their uses.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is on which side of relation you declare the link. If  on child - belongs to, if on parent - has one. Below more explanation using examples from gorm documentation.

Here is User child of Company. You have company id and object inside User. Company knows nothing about users. You can access company from user but not vice versa.
https://gorm.io/docs/belongs_to.html

```
type Company struct {
  ID   int
  Name string
}

type User struct {
  gorm.Model
  Name      string
  CompanyID int
  Company   Company
}
```

Here is CreditCard inside User. UserID in CreditCard, but CreditCard object inside User.
https://gorm.io/docs/has_one.html

```
type User struct {
  gorm.Model
  CreditCard CreditCard
}

type CreditCard struct {
  gorm.Model
  Number string
  UserID uint
}
```

So basically what to choose depends on your use cases. Do you want to be able to access child from parent or parent from child.

Answer (score -1):

Both of them are used to create one-to-one connection with another model, the differences between them I think it's self-explanatory as its documentation said.

[Belongs To](https://gorm.io/docs/belongs_to.html)

```
type User struct {
  gorm.Model
  Name      string
  CompanyID int
  Company   Company
}

type Company struct {
  ID   int
  Name string
}
```

Like the example above, the user can only work in one company, there is no chance user can do other work in multiple companies since the user only belongs to one company.

[Has One](https://gorm.io/docs/has_one.html)

```
type User struct {
  gorm.Model
  CreditCard CreditCard
}

type CreditCard struct {
  gorm.Model
  Number string
  UserID uint
}
```

Otherwise, the has one relationship guarantee that each model can only have one another model. In the example above the user can only have one credit card and the credit card can only belong to exactly one user as its owner.

And when to use one over another depends on the entity and the main business of your application. Thanks, hope that help.

Comment: I still do not see the difference.